# Laravel - can we create a master route that redirects every link to the profile page if the same has not been filled in as yet

Tags: laravel

In laravel, I want the users to create their profile before they can access any other link of the application. Can we create a master route that redirects every link to the profile page if the same has not been filled in as yet.

Comment: Create a middleware which would help you achieve that

Comment: Thanks for your response linktoahref!

Would be better if it is possible via routes. I would prefer it to be as sort as possible.

Please advise on your thoughts for: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/acl-access-control-list-authorization-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 1):

You would have to wrap all your routes in a middleware that checks if their profile has been filled, if this fails then redirect them to the profile page.

Comment: Thanks Ian!

Looks like this will require a composer command. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

one Possible solution would be this :

1. Create a variable for each user to say true if his profile is filled or false if not.
2. then create a middleware to check that variable. if its false to redirect to profile page... your logic. read here for middleware https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware
3. wrap all your routes with that middleware

> in your route file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'yourmiddlewarename'], function() {
                   //all routes 
          });
```

Comment: One problem you may come across with this is that if in future you require more profile fields to be filled out then you would have to set everyone to false. With the check only being in one place you may as well be explicit as to what profile fields you want filled.